# How to cross-compile with .gpr project file and gprbuild?

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling, ada, gnat, gprbuild

I'm trying to cross-compile from Linux (*Fedora 29*) an Ada program with Windows as target. I have no knowledge about compilation and the [Gnat project manager doc](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html) couldn't help the noob I am. 
I would prefer to use switches inside the project file and keep the command the simplest possible. What should I do?

I tried `gprbuild -P logfilter.gpr --target=Windows` which leads to

```
Error: no compiler found for language 'c', target = Windows, default runtime
Error: no compiler found for language 'ada', target = Windows, default runtime
logfilter.gpr:3:09: warning: no compiler specified for language "Ada", ignoring all its sources
logfilter.gpr:7:19: "log_filter_main.adb" is not a source of project "logfilter"
gprbuild: problems with main sources
```

Here is my `gprconfig`:

```
prconfig has found the following compilers on your PATH.
  Only those matching the target and the selected compilers are displayed.
   1. GNAT for Ada in /usr/bin/ version 8.3 (default runtime)
   2. GCC-ASM for Asm in /usr/bin/ version 8.3.1
   3. GCC-ASM for Asm2 in /usr/bin/ version 8.3.1
   4. GCC-ASM for Asm_Cpp in /usr/bin/ version 8.3.1
   5. LLVM for C in /usr/bin/ version 7.0.1
   6. GCC for C in /usr/bin/ version 8.3.1
   7. G++ for C++ in /usr/bin/ version 8.3.1
```

and my `gprconfig --show-targets`:

```
List of targets supported by a compiler:
x86_64-redhat-linux
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

here is my `file.gpr`:

```
with "../../lib/gnat/gtkada";

project LogFilter is
    for Source_Dirs use ("src");
    for Object_Dir  use "obj";
    for Exec_Dir    use "exec";
    for Main use ("log_filter_main.adb");

   package Builder is
      for Executable ("main.adb") use "Logs_Filter";
   end Builder;

   package Compiler is
      for Switches ("ada") use ("-gnat2012");
   end Compiler;

end Logfilter;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have a cross-compiler installed.

Comment: Isn't grpbuild able to cross compile by itself with the good parameters?

Comment: well, no. It needs to know about the target compiler, and your `gprconfig --show-targets` only lists linux targets...

Comment: I noticed it only list linux targets. I will search a cross compiler.

Comment: In general, you need to follow [these instructions](https://wiki.osdev.org/GNAT_Cross-Compiler) to build a gnat cross compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the issue you're encountering is because you're not using a [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).
Just to clarify something about `gprbuild` that might make this clearer: `gprbuild` is just a front-end for the versions of `gcc` and `gnat` on your system. Essentially it's just an Ada-specific analogue of `make`. It processes the project configuration file and works out what parts of the project to be built. From the `gprconfig` output it looks like you're using the FSF GNAT obtained from the Fedora repos. `gprconfig --show-targets` is only showing you the [targets](https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet) of the native Linux compilers that it's found in your `$PATH`.

To solve your problem you'll need to find an Ada compiler targeting Windows. AdaCore provide a pretty decent native Windows compiler if that's an option for you.

Comment: Using Windows native tools gave me the best result with the least frustration. I used GPS on Windows 10 and to correctly run my GtkAda application  I run it into an external terminal... And it works! Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 5):

Once I did this with Fedora 24. But this required to build a cross compiler. I still have a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/reznik/matreshka-cross)

and [patches for fedora packages](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:reznik/mingw-gcc)

I filled a request on fedora to include ada in windows in cross compiler, but they closed it. I'm unable to find the bug number, however.

Tell me if you are interested in fresh version of this or instructions how to use.

Update: I've rebuilt cross for FC29. You can try it this way:

```
dnf copr enable reznik/ada
dnf install mingw64-gcc-gnat
dnf install gprbuild

sed -i -e 's/-pc-mingw/-w64-mingw/g' /usr/share/gprconfig/*

cat > hello.adb << EOF
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Hello is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Hello");
end Hello;
EOF

cat > hello.gpr << EOF
project Hello is
   for Main use ("hello.adb");
end Hello;
EOF
gprbuild --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 -P hello.gpr
file hello.exe

hello.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

PS: [link to copr](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/reznik/ada/)

Comment: When doing `dnf search cross-compiler` I find many mingw64 and 32 packets. -MinGW Windows cross-compiler... Sadly, I don't know if any could work with Ada. However, I'm interested by your solution!

Comment: Unfortunately most of the pre-packaged cross-GCC builds I've seen in Linux distros don't include Ada support. There's some resources online from people who've put in lots of hard work building cross compilers for Ada: https://forward-in-code.blogspot.com/2015/05/building-gcc-510-for-arm-eabi.html This is a bit of a start if you need to go down this path.

Comment: I've compiled cross for FC29 and updated the answer.

Comment: Works very well with your example. However, it doesn't work for my project and generates this error: ```Bind
   [gprbind]      log_filter_main.bexch
   [Ada]          log_filter_main.ali
error: "log_filter_main.adb" must be recompiled ("system.ads" has been modified)
error: "s-stalib.adb" must be compiled
error: ("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/adalib/s-stalib.ali" is obsolete and read-only)
error: "log_filter_handlers.adb" must be recompiled ("system.ads" has been modified)
error: "a-except.adb" must be compiled```  and much more

Comment: Do you have a directive in your project config for using a custom runtime? This looks like an issue with the Ada runtime. I encountered a similar problem once, but from memory that was because I had compiled the runtime with a different compiler.

Comment: doesn't that sed command clobber the native compiler for this installation? It seems to me that you should *add* an alternative rather than overwrite.